# Trying to access a variable outside of $.get() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access variable outside of $.get() in jQuery, but it's not happening.

Here, you'll see that while I'm defining the title, $.get() ignores it. If I define title within $.get(), the title becomes undefined:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        var icon = '';
        var title;
        function paginate(limit) {
            counter=counter+limit;
            $(".flash").show();
            $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html("Loading");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>notes/jq_get_notes_for_browser/" + '<?php echo $results['select_folder_for_browser'][0]['folder_id']; ?>/' + counter,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (element) {
                        $(".flash").hide();
                        $(".load-link").addClass("link-none");
                        for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                            if (element[i].favourite == 'Y') {
                                icon = 'favourite';
                            } else {
                                icon = element[i].status;
                            }
                            $.get('<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>browser/jq_get_string_truncate_to_length/60/' + encodeURIComponent(element[i].title), function(data) {
                                title = decodeURIComponent(data);
                            });
                            $("#data-notes").append('<div class="browser-item-surround-note note-64" id="note-' + element[i].note_id + '"><div class="container"><a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>notes/edit/' + element[i].note_id + '" title="Edit the &lsquo;' + element[i].title + '&rsquo; Note"><img src="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>library/images/ui/icons/browser/notes/note-' + icon + '.png" alt="note" width="64" height="64" /></a><p><a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>notes/view/' + element[i].note_id + '" title="Created on ' + element[i].creation + '. Modified on ' + element[i].modification + '." class="browser-item-note">' + title + '</a></p></div></div>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        paginate(0);
</script>
```

As for $.get() itself, it is returning data, but I just can't access it later on (near to the end of the long .append() in the code sample).

**EDIT**

```
for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
    var el = element[i];
    $.get('<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>browser/jq_get_string_truncate_to_length/60/' + encodeURIComponent(element[i].title), function(data) {
        $("#data-notes").append('< code >' + decodeURIComponent(data) + '< / code >');
    });
}
```

Just to be clear, while Brad's advice works in principle, it's not working in the context of this problem; all of the notes are the same, with the exception of the title. So placing the .append() inside the $.get() is obviously not the solution, unless there's a way to force $.get() to work with the for().

Comment: What variable you define?

Comment: Async strikes again! Your append statement is being evaluated while the `.get()` is still in progress.

Comment: because ajax is asynchronous by default

Answer (score 3):

Declare the variable you need later outside of the scope of the `$.get`, however keep in mind that it may returned `undefined` until the AJAX call has executed (since AJAX runs Async). e.g.

```
var foo
$.get('/some/url',data,function(html){
  foo = html;
]);
```

Then, when you need it:

```
if (foo !== undefined){
  // use foo, otherwise the AJAX hasn't successfully completed.
}
```

Also, because it is AJAX (async) you can't *serially* call it. (i.e. call `$.get` then think the code next line will have access to that variable) It needs to be called *after* a successful query with `$.get`. For example, this will (with 99.9% probably) never work:

```
var foo;
$.get('/some/url',data,function(html){
  foo = html;
});
alert(foo); // fail
```

JS doesn't work like that since AJAX goes off on its own and performs the AJAX call. There's no serial execution here, so you have to wait for the `$.get` callback to return before `foo` will have any definition.

Comment: Brad, I think that's happening, because I'm seeing a delay in the return of the data. Any ideas how I get around that?

Comment: @WayneSmallman: When you need something in AJAX, use it in the callbacl and not outside. This ensures you have the data, but also (in the event of a failure) you have handling code. (maybe using `$.ajaxError` or use `$.ajax` with the `error` parameter)

Comment: @soderslatt: Was trying to keep it simple without getting in to the deferred API. But you certainly can...

Comment: Brad, I've wrapped the .append() in the if() but it's just stopped the whole thing from running, which means the title isn't being accessed outside the $.get(), so I'm none the wiser as to what's going on.

Comment: @WayneSmallman: one of two things: make your original AJAX call perform that post processing (60 character truncate) maybe through an additional argument passed [`&truncate=true`] or otherwise) or place the `.append` within the `$.get` callback function so it's assured to have the information when it's called.

Comment: I just tried that, but there's undefined errors popping up everywhere for the element[i] variable, which I don't know how to stop.

Comment: Okay, figured it out; var el = element[i]; just before the $.get() and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Brads answer is correct, but to solve your problem. Try using the promise from the $.get()

```
    $.get("yourUrl").done(function(data){
        title = decodeURIComponent(data);
        $("#data-notes").append();
    });
```

Comment: Hi, and thanks for the reply. However, I just made an edit to the opening post explaining why that method doesn't work; the loop stops and all of the notes are identical, except for their titles.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, since it's a question of waiting for the $.get() to finish, that became the route to the solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var counter = 0;
        var icon = '';
        function get_note_title (id, title) {
            $.get('<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>browser/jq_get_string_truncate_to_length/60/' + encodeURIComponent(title), function(data) { $('#note-' + id + ' p a').append(decodeURIComponent(data)); });
        }
        function paginate(limit) {
            counter=counter+limit;
            $(".flash").show();
            $(".flash").fadeIn(400).html("Loading");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>notes/jq_get_notes_for_browser/" + '<?php echo (isset($results['select_folder_for_browser'][0]['folder_id'])) ? $results['select_folder_for_browser'][0]['folder_id'] : 0; ?>/' + counter,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (element) {
                        $(".flash").hide();
                        $(".load-link").addClass("link-none");
                        for (var i=0;i<element.length;i++) {
                            if (element[i].favourite == 'Y') {
                                icon = 'favourite';
                            } else {
                                icon = element[i].status;
                            }
                            $("#data-notes").append('<div class="browser-item-surround-note note-64" id="note-' + element[i].note_id + '"><div class="container"><a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>notes/edit/' + element[i].note_id + '" title="Edit the &lsquo;' + element[i].title + '&rsquo; Note"><img src="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>library/images/ui/icons/browser/notes/note-' + icon + '.png" alt="note" width="64" height="64" /></a><p><a href="<?php echo config_item('base_url'); ?>notes/view/' + element[i].note_id + '" title="Created on ' + element[i].creation + '. Modified on ' + element[i].modification + '." class="browser-item-note">' + get_note_title(element[i].note_id, element[i].title) + '</a></p></div></div>');
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
        }
        paginate(0);
</script>
```

Note the use of the get_note_title() function and how it employs .append() to add in the titles retrospectively, and where I use it (near to the end of the long .append() in the code sample).

When the whole thing executes, you see "undefined" for each title for a split second before being appended with the proper title, but I'm sure I can fix that.